# sequence problem $\{s_n\}$ of positive numbers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose that a sequence $\{s_n\}$ of positive numbers satisﬁes the condition   $s_{n+1}> αs_n$  for all $n$ where $α > 1$.

Show that $s_n → ∞$.

Comment: Do you mean $s_{n+1}$?

Comment: Use the sequence $t_n=s_nα^{-n}$. (And please use TeX formatting for entire formulas, not just pieces of them.)

Answer (score 1):

I think it should read $s_{n+1}>\alpha s_n$. Otherwise $s_0=1$, $s_n=\frac{1}{4}s_{n-1}$ is a counterexample ($\alpha=2$).

$s_1>\alpha s_0$ and $s_2>\alpha s_1>\alpha(\alpha s_0)=\alpha^2 s_0$. By itteration $s_n>\alpha^n s_0$. WTS: For all $N$ there exists an $n$ such that $s_n>N$, so we want $N=\alpha^n s_0$. Solving for $n$ gives $n=\log_\alpha (N/s_0)$. Thus for any $n>\log_\alpha (N/s_0)$, $s_n>N$. But $N$ was arbitrary, so it is unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

We have $s_n \ge \alpha^n s_0$. Remember that the geometric sequence $\{\alpha^n\}$ goes to $\infty$ if $\alpha > 1$.

Answer (score 1):

For sake of contradiction suppose that $S:=\{s_n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is bounded above. Let $s=\sup S$ (notice that $s$ is positive). So $s/\alpha<s$; there is a $N$ such that $s_N>s/\alpha$, i.e., $s_{N+1}>\alpha s_N>s$, which contradicts our choice of $s$. Then  $s= \infty$ and so $s_n$ is not bounded, which means that the sequence diverges.